# Outlook.com - Printing Problem

Tags: outlook.com, printing

With Outlook.com - whenever I try to print an email of say 3 pages, it only prints the screen view and 2/3 of the page width. I've resorted to emailing emails I need to print to my "spare" email to print the way I expect. Does anyone have a solution? This used to be fine before upgrading from Hotmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Outlook.com, when viewing an email you should see a dropdown arrow next to "Actions" with an option to "Print message". This will give you a printable version of your email.

[image: Outlook.com Printing option]

Comment: Thanks - I don't have an actions prompt, but have now worked out that clicking the *** in the header bar also gives a dropdown with a print option which is correctly formatted

Comment: Ahh, interesting. It shows for me in IE and Firefox on Windows, but I haven't checked in any other browsers/OS's. What are you using?

Comment: I don't have the Action drop down box nor the three dots.I am using FireFox 20.0.1 I have looked but cannot figure out how to print.